# Convert List<object> to List<U>

Tags: c#

I want to convert `List<Object>` to `List<U>` where as `U` is the type that can be generated Dynamically but List is not accepting `U` in C#

Comment: Could you include how you're planning to use this or how you see this working? It's hard to tell what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6):

If you know that every object inside your list is of type `U`, you can use LINQ to do the conversion:

```
List<U> res = listObj.Cast<U>().ToList();
```

Comment: This is assuming that the objects in the list are actually of type `U` already and requires no conversion.

Comment: If `U` is supposed to be *dynamically generated*, it's not available at compile time. However, you can't say whether the OP used this term deliberately.